# URL shortener who does nothing according to the owner

Tags: url-redirection

I talk in a security forum, and sometimes a moderator share links to sources about things he talk about, but when I hover on these links, the link is different the the source it self. It is actually a URL shortener that he himself built which associated with his website. I thought it is self profit.

**I asked him why he does that**

> What personal gain are you talking about? Do you see an advertisement
> when you click on the link? You get 301 from the server, there is not
> even a BODY for response from the server.

**And then he also added:**

> Think about how it can benefit someone who is in charge of providing
> resources in almost every one of his posts.
>
> I'm the only one who can create shortcuts under this domain.
>
> A. I do not see IP addresses in the UI.
>  B. I see countries of
> origin.
>  C. I see a referrer if the browser has not filtered (so I
> can theoretically know from which forum post they came). 
>  D. I
> have nginx level logs where I can see an IP address. I only access
> this log if I have to worry about problems and even then I do not care
> about the addresses unless it is an attack.
>
> Although I have log systems, the logs are not sent there, because this
> information really does not interest me. The answer obtained is 301
> without content. No advertisements, so no personal gain.

**What can it be? is it sounds like something malicious? I have clicked on his links.**

Comment: Why do you think it's malicious?

Comment: There is nothing for us to tell you. We would have to actually analyse the service, which we won't do.

Comment: @schroeder Why not? I mean, this forum is meant to help people solve their problem. At least speak for yourself, and not ***we** won't do*. Thank you anyway

Comment: @multithr3at3d I am asking if it might be malicious based on the information I provided and based on your knowledge.

Comment: I'm a mod. I speak for "we". This is not a site to help people "solve their problems". We are a Q&A site. That means that there is a certain style and requirements for questions.

Comment: Without more details about what is *actually* happening on his server, we can only guess. So we need more info, and we're not going to do the analysis to get it for you.

Comment: @schroeder yeah I can't really provide any more information so. I thought you can reach conclusions or guess something based on the information I gave. Nevermind, it is not really critical. Thanks

Comment: it's probably just so he can track engagement on the links he provides, otherwise the browser just goes to the link w/o notifying the linking site. He could use GA instead since it does this, but maybe he doesn't like the privacy implications of outside analytics and came up with a simple system of his own design.

Answer (score 2):

This does not sound like anything malicious or even special. It is not that hard to have personal URL shorteners which do just what the name suggest: provide a short URL. These are much easier to share with others than a long URL. There is no need to have extra functionality on top of this when all one wants to do is to provide a short URL.

Also, if somebody wants to share a malicious link they can do just this. It is not clear from a link what is behind it, i.e. not clear if it is malicious or innocent. A URL shortener does not add any layer of obfuscation here since it is not clear from beginning.

This is different with public URL shorteners though: a established and kind of trusted public URL shortener can be used to hide links to malicious resources behind a trusted site. But this is not the case here - the private URL shortener has no more trust than the long URL it points too.

Comment: He does not do that to short the URL. The forum has the same functionally as in *StackExchange*, he use `[link](http://example.com)`. Therefore I still don't understand why he does that..

Comment: @divMi: Then please don't call it URL shortener - a phrase which has an established meaning. What you describe in the comment is simply a link with a (short) description, nothing special about it. Also, it does not match your description regarding a redirect since `[link](url)` does not cause any kind of redirect.

Comment: Haha no, it is a URL shortener but it is also in a format like I sent above. I just said it doesn't the case you think (to make the link look better). He use both the format and the URL shortener to provide resources.